# Delete Sitecore items on multiple environments via a Sitecore package

Tags: package, sitecore

I'm working with a DTAP environment. Each environment has it's own Sitecore database. I'd like to delete some items via a package so I can reuse the package on each environment.

So far I found only ways to programmatically do a delete action like this. But I don't want to write some code in this case.

Anyone an idea how I can do this via a package? Or is it just not possible via Sitecore package?

Thanks!

Comment: Sitecore packages does not support deleting items.

Comment: You can't delete individual items, but you can delete child items with the "Override" option when installing a package, but that is essentially replacing an entire branch.

Comment: With Sitecore package you cannot delete the items but if you want to remove the item from the live site, you may set the items as unpublishable then create the package of these items and install it. When publishing triggers it will remove the item from the target database

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Create package using Sitecore Rocks for the items. Along with this create Anti-Package using Sitecore Rocks. Deploy Anti-Package to revert the changes.

Try this and see if this works.